# Get cursor position on Z = 0 plane using glm::unproject()?

Tags: c++, opengl, cursor, glfw, glm-math

I'm trying to get the coordinates (x,y) of the grid (z = 0) using only the cursor coordinates. After a long search I found this way to do that using the `glm::unproject`.

First I'm getting the cursor coordinates using the callback:

```c++
void cursorCallback(GLFWwindow *window, double x, double y)
{
    this->cursorCoordinate = glm::vec3(x, (this->windowHeight - y - 1.0f), 0.0f);
}
```

an then converting these coordinates:

```c++
glm::vec3 cursorCoordinatesToWorldCoordinates()
{
            glm::vec3 pointInitial = glm::unProject(
                                              glm::vec3(this->cursorCoordinate.x, this->cursorCoordinate.y, 0.0),
                                              this->modelMatrix * this->viewMatrix,
                                              this->projectionMatrix,
                                              this->viewPort
                                              );

            glm::vec3 pointFinal = glm::unProject(
                                              glm::vec3(this->cursorCoordinate.x, this->cursorCoordinate.y, 1.0),
                                              this->modelMatrix * this->viewMatrix,
                                              this->projectionMatrix,
                                              this->viewPort
                                              );

            glm::vec3 vectorDirector = pointFinal - pointInitial;

            double lambda = (-pointInitial.y) / vectorDirector.y;

            double x = pointInitial.x + lambda * vectorDirector.x;
            double y = pointInitial.z + lambda * vectorDirector.z;

            return glm::vec3(x, y, 0.0f);
}
```

I use an ArcBall camera to rotate the world around specified axis, so that is how I generate the MVP matrixes:

```c++
this->position = glm::vec3(0.0f, 10.0f, 5.0f);
this->up = glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
this->lookAt = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

this->fieldView = 99.0f;
this->farDistance = 100.0f;
this->nearDistance = 0.1f;

this->modelMatrix      = glm::mat4(1.0f);
this->viewMatrix       = glm::lookAt(this->position, this->lookAt, this->up) * glm::rotate(glm::degrees(this->rotationAngle) * this->dragSpeed, this->rotationAxis);
this->projectionMatrix = glm::perspective(glm::radians(this->fieldView), 1.0f, this->nearDistance, this->farDistance);
```

But something is going wrong because I'm not getting the right results. Look this print of the application:

[image]

each square is 1 unit, the cube is rendered at position (0, 0, 0). With `rotationAngle = 0` when a put the cursor at (0,0), (1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4), (5,5) I get (0, 5.7), (0.8, 6.4), (1.6, 6.9), (2.4, 7.6), (3.2, 8.2), (4.2, 8.8) respectivally. That's not expected.

- Why `y` is delayed by 6 units?
- It's necessary rotate the result `cursorCoordinatesToWorldCoordinates` based on `rotationAngle` isn't?

--

That I already did:

- Checked if the viewport match with `glViewport` - **OK**
- Checked the opengl coordinates (`Y` is up, not `Z`) - **OK**

Comment: [tag:glm] != [tag:glm-math]

Comment: @httpdigest thanks! But the problem still.

Comment: The z-coordinate of the grid (assuming it lies on xy plane) must play a roll in the final calculus, not only those coming from farPoint, nearPoint. I mean, the unprojected ray must be intersected with the plane where the grid lies.

Comment: @Ripi2 I think I get it, but not... What is wrong?

Comment: The `lambda=` expression is wrong. If all points in the grid are (x,y,K) (K is some fixed z) then `lambda = (K -nearPoint.z) / lineSegment.z`. For other planes you need plane-line intersection. `K -nearPoint.z` means the piece of lineSegment between `nearPoint` and the grid

Comment: @Ripi2 that's right. I updated the question fixing that and showing the new result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to intersect the ray from `glm::vec3(this->cursorCoordinate.x, this->cursorCoordinate.y, 0.0)` to `glm::vec3(this->cursorCoordinate.x, this->cursorCoordinate.y, 1.0)` with the grid in world space, rather than model space (of the cuboid).
You've to skip `this.modelMatrix`:

```cpp
glm::vec3 pointInitial = glm::unProject(
    glm::vec3(this->cursorCoordinate.x, this->cursorCoordinate.y, 0.0),
    this->viewMatrix,
    this->projectionMatrix,
    this->viewPort);

glm::vec3 pointFinal = glm::unProject(
    glm::vec3(this->cursorCoordinate.x, this->cursorCoordinate.y, 1.0),
    this->viewMatrix,
    this->projectionMatrix,
    this->viewPort);
```

---

In any case `this->modelMatrix * this->viewMatrix` is incorrect. If you eant to intersect the ray with an object in model space, then it has to be `this->viewMatrix * this->modelMatrix`. Matrix multiplication is not [Commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property).

Comment: Thanks for the help. All your previous answers are good and helped me to solve the problem. For future readers: remember to check the viewport, opengl coordinates system, obtain correctly the director vector and normalize it.